# Calling an instantiated version of a class I made within a button in another class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

Essentially what I want to do is reference myHashTable from nextStageButton in the InitialScreen class within the addingButton in the ArrayAddingScreen class.  I included comments in my code to try to explain myself better.  I'm really trying to go over the top with this assignment, so if you see anything else I've done wrong or that I could do better, please provide me with that insight, it would be vastly appreciated.  The assignment is making a hashtable and storing Clients on them if anyone was interested

Edit: Trimmed some stuff out for relevance sake

UI screen 1

```
package hashtableinsert;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class InitialScreen extends Application {
//code went here but it wasn't relevant so I took it out
        nextStageButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t)
            {
                if(arraySize.getText().equals("")){
                    errorLabel.setVisible(true);
                }else{
                int passingToN = Integer.parseInt(arraySize.getText());
//I need to reference this in the adding button
                Hashtable myHashTable = new Hashtable(passingToN);
                errorLabel.setVisible(false);
                primaryStage.hide();
                arraySize.clear();

                nextStage = new ArrayAddingScreen(firstStage);

                }
            }               
            });         
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

UI screen 2

```
package hashtableinsert;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class ArrayAddingScreen extends Application {
   //Same as before trimmed for relevance
        addingButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t)
            {
               String nameString = nameInput.getText();
               String cityString = cityInput.getText();               
               Client myClient = new Client(nameString,cityString);
               //I need to access myHashTable here

            }

        });
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Client class

```
package hashtableinsert;
/**
 * Write a description of class Client here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Client
{
    private String name;
    private String city;

    public Client(String name, String city)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + city;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }
}
```

Hashtable class

package hashtableinsert;
    /**
     * Write a description of class HashTable here.
     *
     * @author (your name)
     * @version (a version number or a date)
     */
    public class Hashtable {

```
    private int n;
    private Client[] table;

    public Hashtable(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        table = new Client[n];
    }

    public int hashFunction(String key) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
            sum += (int) key.charAt(i);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public String search(String key) {       
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
            sum += (int) key.charAt(i);
        }

        if (key.equals(table[sum])) {
            return table[sum].toString();
        } else if (table[sum] == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            while (table[sum] != null) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
           return table[sum].toString();
    }

    public boolean insert(Client myClient) {
        int counter = 0;
        String temp = myClient.getName();
        boolean ret = false;
        int tempSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            tempSum += (int) temp.charAt(i);
        }

        if (table[tempSum] == null) {
            table[tempSum] = myClient;
            ret = true;
        } else {
            while (table[tempSum] != null) {
                if(tempSum == table.length){
                    tempSum = -1;
                }
                tempSum++;
                counter++;
            }
            if(counter != n){
             ret = true;  
             table[tempSum] = myClient;
            }
        } 
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Zach, there is too much code here.  Try to narrow down what you want to ask and just show the relevant code.

Comment: As per your request Scary Wombat I trimmed out a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access something in a newly instantiated class then pass it to the class either in its constructor or as a setter method

```
Hashtable myHashTable = new Hashtable(passingToN);
.....
// ArrayAddingScreen needs to read/write myHashTable so we will pass it
nextStage = new ArrayAddingScreen(firstStage, myHashTable);

// OR
// create a setter method in ArrayAddingScreen class

public void setMyhashTable (Hashtable myHashTable) {
   this.myHashTable = myHashTable;
}
```